# Installing Snappy on a HDP Cluster

Tags: hadoop, compression, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, snappy

I have a HBase cluster built using Hortonworks Data Platform 2.6.1.
Now I need to apply Snappy compression on HBase tables.

Without installing Snappy, I executed the Compression Test and I got a success output. I used below commands.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest file:///tmp/test.txt snappy

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest hdfs://hbase.primary.namenode:8020/tmp/test1.txt snappy
```

In got below response for both commands.

```
2017-10-30 11:25:18,454 INFO  [main] hfile.CacheConfig: CacheConfig:disabled
2017-10-30 11:25:18,671 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
2017-10-30 11:25:18,679 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
2017-10-30 11:25:21,560 INFO  [main] hfile.CacheConfig: CacheConfig:disabled
2017-10-30 11:25:22,366 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
SUCCESS
```

I see below libraries in the path /usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native/ as well.

```
libhadoop.a 
libhadooppipes.a 
libhadoop.so 
libhadoop.so.1.0.0 
libhadooputils.a 
libhdfs.a 
libsnappy.so 
libsnappy.so.1 
libsnappy.so.1.1.4
```

Does HDP support snappy compression by default?

If so can I compress the HBase tables without installing Snappy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Without installing Snappy, I executed the Compression Test and I got a success output.

Ambari installed it during cluster installation, so yes those commands are working

> Does HDP support snappy compression by default?

Yes, the HDP-UTILS repository  provides the snappy libraries.

> can I compress the HBase tables without installing Snappy?

Hbase provides other compression algorithms, so yes

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @cricket_007. It was really helpful.